# Dialog plays animation when state changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

I'm using Redux and material-ui

I'm trying to run Dialog with `<Slide direction="up"/>` animation using this attribute: `TransitionComponent`

`email` is a state value that came from reducer and changes when I enter value on `TextField`

When I try to enter some value on, animation plays but, **I want to play it only one time.**

[image]

```js
    interface IProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
      // ...
      setEmail: (email: string) => void;
      email: string;
      // ...
    }
    
    const LoginDialog: React.SFC<IProps> = props => {
      const handleClose = () => {
        props.setIsOpen(false);
      };
    
      const handlePasswordChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        props.setPassword(event.target.value);
      };
    
      const handlePasswordVisibility = () => {
        props.setPasswordVisibility(!props.passwordVisibility);
      };
    
      const handleEmailChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        props.setEmail(event.target.value);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog
            open={props.isOpen}
            //dialog plays animation when props.isOpen changes
            TransitionComponent={props => <Slide direction="up" {...props} />}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="login-dialog-slide-title"
            aria-describedby="login-dialog-slide-description"
            disableBackdropClick={true}
            keepMounted
          >
            <DialogTitle id="login-dialog-slide-title">
              <FormattedMessage id="logindialog_title" />
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <TextField value={props.email} onChange={handleEmailChange} autoFocus type="email" label={<FormattedMessage id="logindialog_email" />}/>
              <TextField type="password" label={<FormattedMessage id="logindialog_password" />} />
              
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                <FormattedMessage id="logindialog_cancle" />
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                <FormattedMessage id="logindialog_ok" />
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default withStyles(styles)(withRouter(LoginDialog));
```

I updated my container which has mapStateToProps and action, reducer for email
and also you can see my full code here: **codesandbox.io/s/nkrmw3wjxj**

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { ICombineReducersState } from "../../../reducers";
import LoginDialog from "./LoginDialog";
import {
  setIsOpen,
  setPassword,
  setPasswordVisibility,
  setEmail,
  setNickname,
  DuplicatedEmail,
  setIsEmailDuplicated
} from "../../../actions";

const mapStateToProps = (state: ICombineReducersState) => ({
  isOpen: state.open.isOpen,
  password: state.password.password,
  passwordVisibility: state.password.passwordVisibility,
  email: state.email.email,
  isPasswordError: state.password.isPasswordError,
  isEmailError: state.email.isEmailError,
  isEmailDuplicated: state.email.isEmailDuplicated
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  setIsOpen: (isOpen: boolean) => dispatch(setIsOpen(isOpen)),
  setPassword: (password: string) => dispatch(setPassword(password)),
  setPasswordVisibility: (passwordVisibility: boolean) =>
    dispatch(setPasswordVisibility(passwordVisibility)),
  setEmail: (email: string) => dispatch(setEmail(email)),
  setNickname: (nickname: string) => dispatch(setNickname(nickname)),
  DuplicatedEmail: () => dispatch(DuplicatedEmail()),
  setIsEmailDuplicated: (isEmailDuplicated: boolean) =>
    dispatch(setIsEmailDuplicated(isEmailDuplicated))
});

export const LoginDialogContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginDialog);
```

```js
export const SET_EMAIL = "SET_EMAIL";
export const SET_IS_EMAIL_DUPLICATED = "SET_IS_EMAIL_DUPLICATED";
import axios from "axios";
import config from "../config";

export interface IEmailAction {
    email: string;
    type: string;
    isEmailDuplicated: boolean;
}

export const setEmail = (email: string) => {
    return {
        email,
        type: SET_EMAIL,
    } as IEmailAction;
};

export const setIsEmailDuplicated = (isEmailDuplicated: boolean) => {
    return {
        isEmailDuplicated,
        type: SET_IS_EMAIL_DUPLICATED,
    } as IEmailAction;
}

export const DuplicatedEmail = () => (dispatch: any):boolean => {
    axios.get(`${config.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/users/email`)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.data.message.length >= 1) {
            return dispatch(setIsEmailDuplicated(true));
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response)
    })

    return dispatch(setIsEmailDuplicated(false));
}
```

```js
import { IEmailAction, SET_EMAIL, SET_IS_EMAIL_DUPLICATED } from "../actions";
export interface IEmailState {
    email: string;
    isEmailError: boolean;
    isEmailDuplicated: boolean;
}

const createEmpty = () => ({
    email: "",
    isEmailError: false,
    isEmailDuplicated: false,
});

const emailRegex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-_.]?[0-9a-zA-Z])*@[0-9a-zA-Z]([-_.]?[0-9a-zA-Z])*.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/i;

export const emailReducer = (state = createEmpty(), action: IEmailAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_EMAIL: {
            return {
                email: action.email,
                isEmailError: !validateEmail(action.email),
                isEmailDuplicated: false,
            } as IEmailState;
        }
        case SET_IS_EMAIL_DUPLICATED: {
            return {
                email: state.email,
                isEmailError: true,
                isEmailDuplicated: action.isEmailDuplicated,
            } as IEmailState;
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const validateEmail = (email: string):boolean => {
    if (emailRegex.test(email)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Please let me know if you need more info about it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is because you are updating the state value of a parent component from your child and when you do that your parent component re renders your child component. Handle email change should update the value of state instead.

Comment: @AmanGupta There isn't any inherent problem in managing the state in a parent component. Handling the state locally would still cause a re-render. A re-render will not cause the transition to re-execute. This problem most likely indicates that this component is being **re-mounted** -- not just re-rendered. I suspect this is due to some problem in an ancestor component. JillAndMe - Please show the parent component code. If the state is managed higher than the immediate parent, show the code for the ancestor that manages the state and any in between.

Comment: A CodeSandbox with the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce this would make it much easier to help you with the problem.

Comment: I realize that since you're using redux, the state won't actually be managed directly in the parent, but at least show the code that is dispatching the changes and that gets the values out of the redux store (most likely via mapStateToProps) to pass to this component (and any code in between).

Comment: I think if @AmanGupta is right I should separate ```<TextField>``` from ```<Dialog>``` with its states

Comment: I generated this sandbox from your GitHub repository: https://codesandbox.io/s/zzlr3lyvz4. I am not able to reproduce the behavior you describe. What browser are you using?

Comment: @RyanCogswell here is my code that reproduce the behavior : https://codesandbox.io/s/nkrmw3wjxj and I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following line was the problem:

```
TransitionComponent={props => <Slide direction="up" {...props} />}
```

By defining this inline it means that the TransitionComponent will look like a new component type with each re-render which then causes that portion of the Dialog to re-mount and therefore redo the transition.

This is easily fixed by defining this outside of your component function as a stable component type (I've called it `TransitionComponent` below) and then using this for the TransitionComponent Dialog prop:

```
const TransitionComponent = props => <Slide direction="up" {...props} />;

const LoginDialog: React.SFC<IProps> = props => {
...
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={props.isOpen}
        TransitionComponent={TransitionComponent}
...
};
```

[image: Edit relay-novel-client]

Comment: I appreciate your response!